# Generating list of React elements server-side

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

Hoping this is just a small issue, but I have this in my Express server:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(App)));
});
```

But there's a problem when I hit:

```
this.posts = positions.map((bool, index) =>
  <Post key={index} pro={bool}/>
);
```

It doesn't seem to recognize the component part:

```
Unexpected token (19:6)
  18 |     this.posts = positions.map((bool, index) =>
> 19 |       <Post key={index} pro={bool}/>
     |       ^
  20 |     );
  21 |   }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you use `babel-node` and do you have `.babelrc` configured?

Comment: I don't, could you point me in the right direction? All I have right now are babel presets/plugins configured through webpack.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use JSX universally, you need to also configure Babel on your server. In order to run `babel-node` you need to install `babel-cli` like this:

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

Inside your project, you need to configure `.babelrc` like this:

(These presets come as separate packages. For example, if you want to use `react` preset, you need to have `babel-preset-react` as project dependency.)

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"] // you can add or remove presets
}
```

Then in your code, where it shows you unexpected token:

```
this.posts = positions.map((bool, index) => (
  <Post key={index} pro={bool} />
));
```

Then you can refactor your `express` route like this:

```
// requires es2015 preset
// you can also use require
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(renderToString(<App />));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `babel-cli` directly as Adrian says or you can wrap your app with `babel-register`. This is only recommended in development environments though and you should compile/transpile your app using babel before running in production.

Assuming you already have your `.babelrc` set up with the `react` and `es2015` plugins, set up an `index.js` with something like:

```
const fs = require('fs-promise');

fs.readFile('./.babelrc').then((babelrc) => {
  const config = JSON.parse(babelrc);
  require('babel-core/register')(config);
  require('./src/server');
});
```

where `./src/server` is your node server app (Express, Hapi, etc.)

And to run it all `NODE_ENV=development node index.js`